# Changing the ownership / permissions of a semaphore

Tags: unix, permissions, semaphore

Is there any way to change the ownership and permission mask for a semaphore on Unix systems directly from the command prompt, without deploying a special program that calls `semctl` with the `IPC_SET` option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any standard utility, but the program listed [here](ftp://ftp.mcs.anl.gov/pub/mpi/misc/semtool.c) can change semaphore modes.

Extending that to also allow changes of ownership should be a pretty trivial exercise.